# Android: Decide to show one activity from Launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, task

I am encountering a serious problem with a complex Android UI I'm developing. I have ActivityA (login, then go to B Activity after calling finish() self) and ActivityB (show user after ActivityA). After user enters ActivityB (after login success), sometimes the network will be cut off and I need to make the user go back to ActivityA. So I receive a  Broadcast Message in ActivityB, when ActivityB receive the broadcast message, it should also finish self and go back to ActivityA. This works fine when ActivityB is foreground. But when ActivityB is in the background, it cannot receive the broadcast message. How can I resolve this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Why are you asking them to login again because the network is offline?  This doesn't make sense to me.  You should indicate the network state in some way and should be able to re-connect when it is live again.

Comment: What is doing the broadcasting?

Comment: as far as I understood you shouldn't really use finish() because android will handle the queue of activities for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user experience for authentication (login) can be a bit tricky since there are several use-cases and variations depending on how you do things and what sort of connection your app has to the server.

Based on your description, it sounds like the app needs to have a persistent connection (like ssh, not http), and when that is cut off, the user needs re-establish the connection and re-authenticate. I would suggest using fragments instead of activities. I would have a login-fragment and the fragment that has the functionality of Activity-B. I'll call that Fragment-B. I'd suggest this basic flow:

1. Within onStart() of the activity, if the user is not logged in, show the login fragment, else show fragment B.
2. On successful authentication, show fragment B.
3. If while the app is in the foreground and connection is lost, switch to the login fragment.

This will handle the 3 situations with the same code:

1. The user is not logged in and must authenticate before using the app. The test in onStart will show the login fragment.
2. The app is in the foreground and loses connection.
3. The app is in the background and loses connection. When the user brings the app back to the foreground, the test in onStart will show the login fragment.

If the connection is not persistent, such as using a REST api with the server, then it is a different problem because the authentication token needs to be cached and the app may not know the user is no longer authenticated until the app accesses the server. (This doesn't sound like your case though.)

Comment: Yes, as your description, the authentication is very hard to implement and you must be an expert to resolve the problem. Thanks for your teaching.

Answer (score 0):

You must be unregistering the reciever in onPause or onStop.

Leave it registered until onDestroy() so it works even if not in the foreground.

Edit: although eskimoapps makes a good point. Maybe activity A just gathers users credentials. Activity B could do the actual connecting. That means if the network goes away Activity B re-establishes it without the user being bothered. Thats more "Android"